# binary search trees code

Tags: c++, tree, destructor, binary-search-tree

wanting to write a destructor for binary search tree (its supposed to delete all the nodes in a tree) here is what i got so far

```
virtual ~BST() {
  BSTNode<Data>* node = root;
  if (node == NULL){
    return;
  }else if (node->left) {
      while(node->left){
        delete node;
      }
  }else if (node->right){
      while(node->right)
        delete node;
  }
        isize = 0;
}
```

i know however there is something wrong with the code, how can i fix it

Comment: Show us the BST class and the BSTNode class.

Answer (score 3):

Lose the `else`s. Otherwise if the tree has `left`. `right` will not be deleted.

Lose the `while`. Nodes should have their own destructors and should delete recursively.

Finally lose the `if`s. Because delete NULL is valid.

```
virtual ~BST() {
  BSTNode<Data>* node = root;
  if (node == NULL){
    return;
  }  
  delete node->left;
  delete node->right;
  isize = 0;
}
```

Comment: This may only delete the roots immediate children, leaving the rest of the tree "in the wind" so to say.

Comment: right, that's what i was thinking, i however need one that deletes all the nodes

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ya It is not really clear how he implemented the relations between BST and BSTNode. I asked him to show but he didn't. I am assuming here that since he has left and right in the node, those nodes also have left and right. What I mean is BST is is just a wrapping around the actual tree structure. But then again I am not sure. This can be way wrong. That's why I mentioned to him that nodes should have their own destructors and delete recursively.

Comment: @AndyT so when all the nodes are deleted the size can then be set to 0 since there is 0 nodes in the tree, i could be wrong though

Comment: @cloud9resident: who cares if it's the last line of destructor?

Answer (score 3):

```
void BST::deleteNode(BSTNode<Data> *node) {
    if (node) {
        deleteNode(node->left);
        deleteNode(node->right);
        delete node;
    }
}

BST::~BST() {
    deleteNode(root);
}
```

Comment: would this delete all the nodes recursively, not just the immediate nodes?

Comment: @cloud9resident Yes this looks like it will properly delete all children.

Answer (score 1):

When you do e.g.

```
while(node->left){
    delete node;
}
```

You delete the node, but do not actually loop to the next one. So the next time in the loop `node` will not be `NULL` so you dereference an unallocated data structure which is *undefined behavior*, and may lead to a crash. And then you try to delete the same `node` *again* which is still undefined behavior and may most certainly lead to a crash.

You also won't delete *both* left and right nodes, only one of them due to the `else`.

I suggest you put a proper destructor in the `BSTNode` which deletes its own children:

```
template<typename T>
BSTNode<T>::~BSTNode()
{
    delete left;
    delete right;
}
```

Then the destructor of the tree would simply be:

```
BST::~BST()
{
    delete root;
}
```